# Drilling hole in wall near dryer vent?

Tags: drywall, screws, dryer, vent, washer

I am trying to install a simple shelf on my wall near my laundry washer and dryer. I just measured the length of the shelf and I have to drill a hole and put an anchor/screw above where the dryer vent seems to go inside a cavity and upward. I don’t want to damage anything related to the dryer/washer so I want to ask if it would be safe to drill here or should I shorten the shelf length?

[image]

I have marked x where I need to drill one of the two holes.

Comment: It would help to know where the vent goes (up the wall, or turns 90 degrees to head horizontally maybe?) Looking where the outside vent is might help. As a side note, that metallized plastic hoop "ducting" is probably very flammable and the hoop nature will trap lint inside, which is also flammable. These days, it's best to stick with rigid or semi-rigid metal ducting.

Comment: You *never* want to put screws for any serious shelves into anything other than studs. (Trust me - I've seen what happens when you try to rely on various hollow wall anchors.)  The dryer vent is going between the studs. So you really have no conflict, provided you correctly identify the studs first, which should not be that hard to do.

Comment: Get a longer shelf to reach the studs

Comment: @RohitGupta maybe the shelf has a mount that's Y distance from the end, where Y is the distance from the corner to the X on the wall.